# Conditional combo boxes are not working properly

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm developing a uwp app written in C#. My app uses `prism.windows`.

The app has two combo boxes. The first one is the selection of countries. The next one shows cities of the country which is selected in the first combo box.

I select Japan in the first combo box, Tokyo is shown in the next combo box. Next I select United States, Tokyo is still shown in the next one.

Chicago and Dayton should be shown in the next one.

```
namespace TestComboBox2.ViewModels
{
    public class MainPageViewModel:BindableBase
    {
        public Views.MainPage View { get; private set; } = null;

        public void Initialize(Views.MainPage mainPage)
        {
            View = mainPage;
        }
        public MainPageViewModel()
        {
            ChangeGroupId();
        }
        private List<CbGroup> CbGroupList = new List<CbGroup>();
        public List<CbGroup> CbGroupLists
        {
            get { return CbGroupList; }
            set { this.SetProperty(ref this.CbGroupList, value); }
        }
        private List<CbItem> CbItemList = new List<CbItem>();
        public List<CbItem> CbItemLists
        {
            get { return CbItemList; }
            set { this.SetProperty(ref this.CbItemList, value); }
        }

        private string txGroupId;
        public string TxGroupId
        {
            get { return txGroupId; }
            set
            {
                this.SetProperty(ref this.txGroupId, value);
                ChangeItemId(txGroupId);
            }
        }
        private string txItemId;
        public string TxItemId
        {
            get { return txItemId; }
            set { this.SetProperty(ref this.txItemId, value); }
        }
        private void ChangeGroupId()
        {
            CbGroupList.Add(new CbGroup("A", "Japan"));
            CbGroupList.Add(new CbGroup("B", "United States"));
            CbGroupList.Add(new CbGroup("C", "CANADA"));
        }
        private void ChangeItemId(string ValueId)
        {
            try
            {
                if (CbItemLists != null)
                {
                    CbItemList.Clear();
                }
                TxItemId = null;
                //
                switch (ValueId)
                {
                    case "A":
                        CbItemList.Add(new CbItem("A1", "Tokyo"));
                        break;
                    case "B":
                        CbItemList.Add(new CbItem("B1", "Chicago"));
                        CbItemList.Add(new CbItem("B2", "Dayton"));
                        break;
                    case "C":
                        CbItemList.Add(new CbItem("C1", "Toronto"));
                        CbItemList.Add(new CbItem("C2", "Halifax"));
                        CbItemList.Add(new CbItem("C3", "Edmonton"));
                        break;
                }
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                string stErrMessage = ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
    public class CbGroup
    {
        public string GroupId { get; set; }
        public string GroupName { get; set; }
        public CbGroup(string ValueId, string ValueName)
        {
            GroupId = ValueId;
            GroupName = ValueName;
        }
    }
    public class CbItem
    {
        public string ItemId { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public CbItem(string ValueId, string ValueName)
        {
            ItemId = ValueId;
            ItemName = ValueName;
        }
    }
}
```

```
<Page
    x:Class="TestComboBox2.Views.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TestComboBox2"
    xmlns:views="using:TestComboBox2.Views"
    xmlns:viewmodels="using:TestComboBox2.ViewModels"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Page.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Style.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlckFontSize}"
                       Text="Country"
                           Foreground="Black"
                       />
                <ComboBox Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStype}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding CbGroupLists,Mode=OneWay}"
                      SelectedValue="{Binding TxGroupId,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      SelectedValuePath="GroupId"
                      >
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock>
                            <Run Text="{Binding GroupName,Mode=OneWay}"/>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlckFontSize}"
                           Foreground="Black"
                       Text="City"
                       />
                <ComboBox Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStype}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding CbItemLists,Mode=OneWay}"
                      SelectedValue="{Binding TxItemId,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      SelectedValuePath="ItemId"
                      >
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock>
                            <Run Text="{Binding ItemName,Mode=OneWay}"/>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>

            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

The second combo box shows the city of the country which is selected in the first combo box.

Comment: Please share your xaml code.

Comment: Hi fuzz. I added my xaml code.

Comment: Please check the following answer.

Comment: Hi Nico. Thank you for your reply. The problem has been solved. The two combo boxes work properly now. Wonderful!

Comment: Hi Nico. I marked your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Conditional combo boxes are not working properly

Please change the type of `CbItemList` to [`ObservableCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.8) that represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed. It will work.

```
private ObservableCollection<CbItem> CbItemList = new ObservableCollection<CbItem>();
public ObservableCollection<CbItem> CbItemLists
{
    get { return CbItemList; }
    set { this.SetProperty(ref this.CbItemList, value); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, You should use ObservableCollection instead of List, because ObservableCollection is a type collection that provides notifications when items get added or removed. ObservableCollection class have own implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged. So when this collection has some changes, It reflects or notifies to UI. So do some modification you code

```
private ObservableCollection<CbItem> CbItemList 
public ObservableCollection<CbItem> CbItemLists
{
    get { return CbItemList ?? (CbItemList = new ObservableCollection<CbItem>()); }
    set { this.SetProperty(ref this.CbItemList, value); }
}
```